# Annotations for Windows store apps/WinRT?

Tags: pdf, windows-8

I'm going to build a Windows Store app in C#, with the capability to annotate PDF's
Is there a library that supports PDF annotations for Windows store apps/WinRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company I work for develops the [XFINIUM.PDF](http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-wpf-silverlight-winrt/xfinium-pdf-overview.html) library. It supports WinRT platform and it supports adding annotations to PDF files.

You can add a text annotation to an existing PDF file like this:

```
// Load the PDF file
PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument(sourcePdfStream);
// Create the annotation and add it to the first page
PdfTextAnnotation ta = new PdfTextAnnotation();
document.Pages[0].Annotations.Add(ta);
// Set the annotation properties
ta.Location = new PdfPoint(50, 50);
ta.Author = "John doe";
ta.Contents = "I am a text annotation.";
ta.IconName = "Note";
// Save the document
document.Save(destinationPdfStream)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mihai for the support.But there is no pdf viewer for your library.is there any?

Comment: Not yet but it will be during Q1 2015

Comment: @MihaiIancu How about now? What's the status of development of viewer  for WinRT from Xfinium? We are looking forward to your components...

Comment: The PDF rendering engine is ready, we're working on the viewer control around it. It will be available soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Amyuni PDF Creator for WinRT](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatorwinrt/), the library allows adding annotations (also pictures, lines, or text), and it provides a graphic component that can display the file on the screen.